# scope of this reference in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

```
var obj = {     
    doIt : function(){
       console.log(this)
    }
}
$('a').on('click', function(){
    obj.doIt(); // this now refers to object      
});

$('a').on('click', obj.doIt); // this refers to anchor tag.
```

In the **first case**, this refers to the Object, but in the **second case** it refers to anchor tag. How come the this changes to object back when we call the function inside an another function **and** why?.

Comment: Because the [`this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) depends on the invocation of the function - it has no "scope"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` is manipulated by jQuery so that you can easily access the DOM element that has been selected or whose event has fired. This can obviously cause issues when it comes to applying object's methods as the context of `this` is lost.

Look at jQuery's [`.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method. That'll allow you to scope the `this` to refer to the `obj`'s context.

```
$("a").on( "click", $.proxy(obj.doIt, obj));
```

To understand the differences in your situations, you need to understand that the function referenced as the second argument (or third...) to the `.on()` method is applied/called in the context of the DOM element. That is, the `this` within the function refers to the element. However, in your first example, you're simply calling your `obj.doIt()` method without any preset context, and so the `this` refers to the `obj`.

Comment: I knew about the proxy() method, its somewhat similar native JS call and apply method. how come the value of this changed when its inside a function call?.

Comment: Updated :) - maybe that explains it better.